# i am having error with open and closing keys

Tags: java, android

I am creating a profile for my user but i dont know why i am getting this error

pls can you look ate the code and tell me what is wrong thank you very much

```
public class Profile extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText editText;
ImageView imageView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile2);

        editText =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.nome);
        imageView=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.foto);


        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
    };
}





}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class Profile extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText editText;
ImageView imageView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile2);

    editText =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.nome);
    imageView=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.foto);


    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    }); 
    // the closing parathesis ')' of setOnClickListener was missing
}

}
```

Comment: hamza thank you verry much, can you pls tell me what was wrong ?

Comment: you forgot to close Parenthesis of "setOnClickListener",

Comment: Please don't just dump code as an answer, explain your answer and describe how it solves the problem.

Comment: just added a brief explanation